# Regex that captures single/double quotes and parenthesis

Tags: php, regex, quotes, parentheses

Using the following regex in PHP, I am able to filter out strings from our application files that look like __('test string'), for translation purposes.

```
preg_match_all('/__\((?:(?:[\"]([^\"\)]*?)[\"](?:,[^\)]*)?)|(?:[\']([^\'\)]*?)[\'](?:,[^\)]*)?))\)/', $contents, $matches)
```

However, I'm stuck figuring out how to capture strings that contain parenthesis themselves, without breaking the ability to parse strings that have both single (') and double (") quotes.

This example in gSkinner's RegExr shows the issue: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?35joj

Anybody out there feeling like a regex ninja today? Thanks in advance. Also, whoo, first post.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would need a [recursive regex](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html).

Comment: Alternatively the [tokenizer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.tokenizer.php). Albeit a regex is sufficient if you only need to match for constant strings, not string expressions (and even then might be more concise with a regex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it: `__\(('|")[^__]+('|")\)`.

Comment: That will break when there is more than one `__()` because it will match everything between the first open and the last close.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are multiple strings to detect and capture per file.

Comment: What if there are underscores in the strings?

Comment: True, but how likely is that? I think no matter how perfect a solution is, if it solves a problem, it is a solution.

Comment: Underscores should not be a problem, these are all user facing strings. Even the parenthesis were pretty rare. Accepting this one, thanks!

Comment: Actually, by using negative lookahead you can create a regex that will accept underscores. e.g. `__\(('|")(?:(?!__\().)+('|")\)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track.

```
 #  "/__\\((?:\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"|'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*')\\)/"


 __\(
 (?:
      " [^"\\]* (?: \\ . [^"\\]* )* "
   |  
      ' [^'\\]* (?: \\ . [^'\\]* )* '
 )
 \)
```